# Add rounded corners on right to Bootstrap Segmented input group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create input group with **input + dropdown + button**

http://jsfiddle.net/eRzDq/127/ This is my example

```
<div class="col-md-10">    
    <h3 id="btn-groups-single">Segmented dropdown groups</h3>        
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="username"/>

      <div class="input-group-btn">
          <!--simple button-->   
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Simple</button>
          <!--dropdown button-->    
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>      
    </div>    
  </div>
```

My problem is that i don't know how to make rounded corners for Simple-Button.
If i change order (swap simple button with dropdown button and add class `.dropdown-toggle` to dropdown) then behaviour is what i want.

So what class i need add to simple button to make it rounded on right? (I think add class `.dropdown-toggle` to simple button is not good solution)

Answer (score 4):

if you have a local StyleSheet:

```
.btn { border-top-right-radius: 5px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; }
```

---

Otherwise there is also a css class type usually used for footers that's called well and has border-radius,

it's oldschool Bootstrap (I usually avoid it since it's been abused) but you could recycle it for your needs

`.well-sm` or `.well-small` should do the trick

Comment: yes, it's obvious solution. But i want to resolve this problem just with bootstap classes. If there is no wished solution, then yes, i will use your. Thanks

Comment: I doubt there is a class in Bootstrap to handle rounded edges on a specific element like that. Most are general, like `well` or `panel`, etc.

Comment: best option is to create a custom selector with `border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;`